# MySQL Merge Two Tables together

Tags: mysql, merge

I'm not the best in MySQL but currently on a tidy up task, not sure if this is possible or ill have to make a script to do this using inserts.

But i have two tables AccountInfo and AccountLogin they both share the same PK so id1 will match id1 in the other table. What im trying to do is get both tables merged into one table either called Account or merge into a table of the two and rename after.

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to merge and create a completely new table? Or do you want a view, that just shows them like when they are merged? Or just an SQL to select them with a join?

Comment: you can do a INSERT INTO table VALUES (SELECT...). For the SELECT part just use a JOIN ON id to get all the values. The table you build will contain all the fields of the two tables (or those you need)

Comment: @Adder take AccountLogin and AccountInfo merge them into new table Members if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Create table "Members" with columns: id, other columns of AccountInfo, other columns of AccountLogin.

Then, like Lelio Faieta said, INSERT INTO Members SELECT id, other columns of AccountInfo ai, other columns of AccountLogin al FROM AccountInfo ai INNER JOIN AccountLogin al ON (al.id = ai.id).

Also, if there are AccountInfo rows without matching AccountLogin rows you can use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.

Disclosure: I usually use Oracle, so I might make a mistake with MySQL.